# ASP MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

now this is probably an stupid question but i'm new to mvc and can't seem to get it working.

Here is what i would like to be able to do with the urls/routes:

1) www.domain.com/name/home/index
2) www.domain.com/home/index

where both the home controllers are seperate controllers and the name part will very but all must go to the same controller and the name should be an param for all the actions in there.

Is this at all possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That seems like horrible, horrible design just by the token of how complicated it is to describe. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but I think that it would be more usual to see

```
www.domain.com/home/index
www.domain.com/home/index/name
```

My initial thinking was that an overloaded `Index` action method would make sense, but [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2596/daniel-schaffer) pointed out that this not allowed (at least not in the manner I suggested).

Updated answer...

Your `Index` action method could take a `string name` argument, and your routes would need to contain something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = "" }
```

In your action method a quick `null` check will tell you whether a `name` was included in the URL or not.

Comment: You can't overload actions in ASP.NET MVC, except by differing both method signature and HTTP verbs.